# Move to another client if there is no connection/authentication MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

i am using mailkit to access a list of pop3clients . For test purposes i have a client that will not authenticate and i wrote an if statement for authentication true to do some task . But instead of moving to another client it throws an exception and stops the process .What should i implement or add to my code to be able in moving to another client in case of no connection or authentication.

```
       public void connect(){
try
        {

            foreach (ObjectDeserializer obj in mailDeserialization.ListOfObjects())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.toString());

                if (obj.port == 995)
                {
                    using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
                    {
                        client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

                        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;


                        client.Connect(obj.server, obj.port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

                        client.Authenticate(obj.user, obj.password);

                        if (client.IsAuthenticated == true)
                        {


                            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var message = client.GetMessage(i);



                                Console.WriteLine(message.From.ToString());
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (Pop3Client clientNoSSL = new Pop3Client(new ProtocolLogger("pop3.log")))
                    {
                        clientNoSSL.Connect(obj.server, obj.port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

                        Console.WriteLine(clientNoSSL.IsConnected.ToString());

                        clientNoSSL.Authenticate(obj.user, obj.password);



                        if (clientNoSSL.IsAuthenticated == true)
                        {

                            for (int i = 0; i < clientNoSSL.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var message = clientNoSSL.GetMessage(i);

                                Console.WriteLine(message.From.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("No");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: If you have a for loop put the exception handler inside the for loop so when an exception occurs code goes to next item in loop instead of jumping outside the for loop.

Comment: @jdweng didn't help :(

Comment: Except handler(s) need to be inside for loop.  You have only one exception handler and it is outside for loop.  You need two exception handler.  One for each for loop.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried after your previous comment and it didn't help

Comment: You have to step through code and debug.do see what is happening.  I will help when you give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jdweng has mentioned in the comments, what you need to do is this:

```
public void connect()
{
    foreach (ObjectDeserializer obj in mailDeserialization.ListOfObjects())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.toString());

        using (var client = new Pop3Client ())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
            client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

            try {
                client.Connect(obj.server, obj.port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                client.Authenticate(obj.user, obj.password);

                for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
                {
                    var message = client.GetMessage(i);
                    Console.WriteLine(message.From.ToString());
                }

                client.Disconnect (true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex);

                if (client.IsConnected)
                    client.Disconnect (false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also taken the liberty of simplifying your code a bit by removing the need for your if/else logic of checking the ports for 2 reasons:

1. Since you are using `Auto` for the SSL mode, what this means is that MailKit will try to upgrade to an SSL/TLS connection after it connects to a plain-text port if the server supports the `STARTTLS` (or `STLS` in POP3's case) command which means that the validation callback and certificate revocation properties *might* be needed.
2. Even if they are not needed, it won't break a plain-text-only connection because those properties won't be used.

I should probably warn that using `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;` is insecure and will allow MITM attacks. I used to have that hack in my README because developers running their code on Mono on Linux, for example, would often not have any Root CA certificates in their SSL certificates database and so every SSL connection they made would fail because of the inability to validate any SSL certificate. Another reason was because self-signed SSL certificates are so common on home mail servers.

Starting with MailKit 2.6.0, MailKit has a default ServerCertificateValidationCallback implementation that already knows the fingerprint and other identifying information for the most common IMAP, SMTP and POP3 mail servers and so that hack is no longer needed in most cases.